# ReactJS: Creating a counter class that increments by a dynamic value (passed through props and stored in state)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

Here is some code that produces a functioning example, it should work if you open it in firefox (I had problems with chrome).

When you click a button, the number beside the word count is incremented by the value displayed on the button (either 1, 5 or 10).

**Code which produces Desired Output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>React tutorial</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.14.7/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@0.14.7/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lesson5challengestyling.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

    var CounterChallenge = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          count: 0
        }
      },
      incrementCountByOne: function(value) {
        this.setState({
          count: this.state.count + 1
        })
      },
      incrementCountByFive: function() {
        this.setState({
          count: this.state.count + 5
        })
      },
      incrementCountByTen: function() {
        this.setState({
          count: this.state.count + 10
        })
      },
      render: function() {
        return (
          <div className="container">
            <h1>Count: {this.state.count}</h1>
            <button className="btn blue-btn" onClick={this.incrementCountByOne}>Add 1</button>
            <button className="btn green-btn" onClick={this.incrementCountByFive}>Add 5</button>
            <button className="btn purple-btn" onClick={this.incrementCountByTen}>Add 10</button>
          </div>
        )
      }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
      <CounterChallenge />,
      document.getElementById('app')
    );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------

I am trying to write this program in a different way, by creating a button class which only has one increment function(instead of increment1, increment5, increment10 like you can see in the code above.)

I would like the code below to perform exactly as the code above.

I am initialing the state of a variable called count in the the core class(Challenge) which react renders to the DOM. Within the class ChallengeButton, I am incrementing the value stored in count(by either 1, 5 or 10 depending on what value is passed in the variable incCount)

I am not sure what is wrong with it, all I really know is that my browser displays a blank white screen. When I inspect the element I receive no helpful information.

**My Program(Which I would like to debug)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>React tutorial</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.14.7/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@0.14.7/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.2/browser.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lesson5challengestyling.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

      var ChallengeButton = React.createClass({
        increment: function(){
          this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + this.props.incCount
          })
        },
        render: function(){
          return{
            <button onClick={this.increment} incCount={this.props.incCount}></button>
          }
        }
      });

      var Challenge = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function(){
          return{
            count: 0
        },
        render: function(){
          return {
            <div>
              <h1>Count: {this.state.count}</h1>
              <ChallengeButton className="blue-btn" incCount='1'/>
              <ChallengeButton className="red-btn" incCount='5' />
              <ChallengeButton className="green-btn" incCount='10' />
            </div>
          }
       }
      });

      ReactDOM.render(
        <Challenge />,
        document.getElementById('app')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------

---

**Accompanying CSS file(Needs no debugging)**

```
body {
  padding: 40px;
  font-family: "helvetica neue", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  color: black;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 36px;
}
.container .btn {
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: 15px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn.blue-btn {
  background-color: #55acee;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #3C93D5;
}

.btn.blue-btn:hover {
   background-color: #6FC6FF;
}

.btn.blue-btn {
  background-color: #55acee;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #3C93D5;
}

.btn.blue-btn:hover {
   background-color: #6FC6FF;
}

.btn.green-btn {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #15B358;
}

.btn.green-btn:hover {
  background-color: #48E68B;
}

.btn.purple-btn {
  background-color: #9b59b6;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #82409D;
}

.btn.purple-btn:hover {
  background-color: #B573D0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here were a few important things.

The buttons were created as functions and not a class.

```
  var ChallengeButton = function(props) {
    return (
      <button className={props.style} onClick={props.func}> Add {props.incCount} </button>
    )
  };
```

And moved the `increment` function to the main class
That function had the word "props" as an argument. When referencing props for ChallengeButton, I had to use `props.*` and could not use `this.props.*`; if the class `Challenge` had props however, then I could use `this.props.*` within the Challenge class.

This is a working script.

```
<script type="text/babel">

      var ChallengeButton = function(props) {
        return (
          <button className={props.style} onClick={props.func}> Add {props.incCount} </button>
        )
      };

      var Challenge = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
          return {
            count: 0
        }
      },
      increment: function(value) {
        this.setState({
           count: this.state.count + value
         })
      },
      render: function() {
        return (
          <div className="container">
            <h1>Count: {this.state.count}</h1>
            <ChallengeButton style="btn blue-btn" incCount='1' func={this.increment.bind(this, 1)} />
            <ChallengeButton style="btn green-btn" incCount='5' func={this.increment.bind(this, 5)} />
            <ChallengeButton style="btn purple-btn" incCount='10' func={this.increment.bind(this, 10)} />
          </div>
        )
     }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Challenge />,
      document.getElementById('app')
    );
    </script>
```